# Enum deserializes to 0 for invalid values

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have an API which is initialized as follows:

```
var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
formatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true });
```

My enum looks similar to following:

```
public enum EventType
{        
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 5,        
    Value3 = 3,
    Value4 = 4        
}
```

And the class where it used as follows:

```
public class ManualEventModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public EventType EventType { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I call the API with `EventType=Value5` or any other illegal value, I get no error but the value of the property `EventType` is set to 0.

How do I filter out the illegal values?

Comment: what do you want it to set the property as?

Comment: Try setting EventType property to a nullable. It might yield the behaviour you seek.

Comment: I've tested this with version `10.0.3` of `Newtonsoft.Json` and it throws an exception.

Comment: @SimonGates great! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I tried with `Newtonsoft.Json` version `10.0.3` - no exception but the enum property is deserialized to 0.

Comment: I tested with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ManualEventModel>`, not sure what the difference is. Anyway, glad you have it working with the nullable approach.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I'm deserializing manually but I use `[FromBody]` in my API method.